# How to convert string value to custom type in function

Tags: go, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I've written a function for role checking:

```golang
...
role = "roles/cloudkms.publicKeyViewer"
func checkRole(key, serviceAccount, role string) bool {
...
return policy.HasRole(serviceAccount, role)
}
```

Then I'm getting the error "cannot use role (type string) as type "cloud.google.com/go/iam".RoleName in argument to policy.HasRole.

What's the right way to convert the role value to custom type?

[The library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/iam/iam.go):

```golang
// A RoleName is a name representing a collection of permissions.
type RoleName string

// Common role names.
const (
    Owner  RoleName = "roles/owner"
    Editor RoleName = "roles/editor"
    Viewer RoleName = "roles/viewer"
)

const (
    // AllUsers is a special member that denotes all users, even unauthenticated ones.
    AllUsers = "allUsers"

    // AllAuthenticatedUsers is a special member that denotes all authenticated users.
    AllAuthenticatedUsers = "allAuthenticatedUsers"
)


// HasRole reports whether member has role r.
func (p *Policy) HasRole(member string, r RoleName) bool {
    return memberIndex(member, p.binding(r)) >= 0
}
```

Comment: use [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions): `policy.Role(role)` or declare your variable as a `policy.Role` to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use type conversion as the following:

```
return policy.HasRole(serviceAccount, iam.RoleName(role))
```

Or simpler by declaring role as `iam.RoleName`

```
func checkRole(key, serviceAccount, role iam.RoleName) bool {
...
   return policy.HasRole(serviceAccount, role)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to me you mean ```return policy.HasRole(serviceAccount, policy.RoleName(role))``` in the first example (case typos). But I'm getting the error "policy.RoleName undefined (type *"cloud.google.com/go/iam".Policy has no filed of method RoleName)"